# Flip D3 Tree Diagram Vertical

Tags: d3.js

The following D3js tree diagram is horizontal. How do I flip it to be vertical? Thank you. Below is part of the code. The full code can be found at this url https://codepen.io/EleftheriaBatsou/pen/LmddvN

```
root = d3.hierarchy(treeData, function(d) { return d.children; });
root.x0 = barchart_height / 2;
root.y0 = 0;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trees are vertical by default -- it's your example which has put it sideways. Lookup at the way groups' transform and paths' d attributes are built, they have their use of x and y swapped

```
return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
```